# What tools/methods could I use in Rails to get information from an Outside URL?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im looking for a way to attain the largest Image in the  of an outside URL in rails. For example, a URL will be provided. The server side will scan the HTML of the page and then "grab" the largest image it finds, and download it (or gather its link).

Would anyone know what tools I could use to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly-speaking there are two ways to do this, either by yourself or by plugging into an outside service.

If you want to do this yourself, I'd suggest using the [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) gem, which allows you to parse an HTML page and pull out the tags you want. For example, to get all image links from a page, you would do this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('<INSERT URL HERE>'))

doc.css('img').each do |link|
  puts link.attr("src").value
end
```

To get the largest image, you'll have to actually determine their size. The "[fastimage](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage)" gem looks like it would be useful for that.

The other option is to use an outside service for doing this. I'd suggest checking out [embedly](http://embed.ly/), for which there is a [gem](https://github.com/embedly/embedly-ruby). If you think you may be planning to need any other info from these links in the future, I think this would be the better route to take, although note that to access the version of the service which gets you the largest images ([preview](http://embed.ly/docs/endpoints/1/preview)) you need to actually pay a monthly fee.

Answer (score 2):

Nokogiri is great, but for this task you really want mechanize:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get 'http://www.amazon.com/'
```

You need to download all the images before you can determine the largest one.

```
images = page.images.map{|image| agent.get image.url}
largest = images.max_by{|image| image.body.size}
largest.save
```

If downloading all the images seems like too much you could consider making HEAD requests and comparing the content-length response headers.

Comment: wow I didn't know you could do that with mechanize. +1 from me.